# Print Hexagonal pattern using asterisk

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am practising to print various types of patterns and I am stuck at Hexagonal Pattern. I am printing it using Asterisk(*).

It should be dynamic. I have almost completed it but stuck at last part. I have divided all parts in chunks and executing all chunks using while loop and if condition.

```
sideLength = 5

totalLength = (sideLength)*2 + (sideLength-2)

loop =1

while loop<=totalLength :
    if (loop==1) or (loop==totalLength):
        print " "*((totalLength - sideLength)//2) + "*"* sideLength + " "*((totalLength- sideLength)//2)

    if loop>(sideLength-1) and loop<= (sideLength-1)+sideLength:
        print "*" + " "*(totalLength-2) + "*"

    if (loop>=1) and (loop)<(sideLength-1):
        print " "*(sideLength- 1- loop) + "*" +  " " * ((sideLength-2) + 2*(loop)) + "*" + " "*(sideLength- 1- loop)

    if loop>((totalLength//2) + (sideLength//2)) and loop<(totalLength-1):
        print " "*(loop - 1 - sideLength ) + "*"

    loop+=1
```

Problem occuring from this last if condition.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Instead of putting image. Please copy paste the code here itself.

Comment: When posting a screenshot of your code, you expect us to retype the whole code. Since you want help, try to be as helpful as possible. This includes a text copy of the relevant parts of your code, as well as the error (or wrong output) you are receiving. See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work on arbitrary lengths>1, you have to change the second if-statement. I fixed the last one for you:

```
sideLength = 5
totalLength = (sideLength) + 2*(sideLength-1)

loop = 1

while loop<=totalLength :
    if loop==1 or loop==totalLength:
        print " "*(sideLength-1) + "*"* sideLength + " "*(sideLength-1)

    if loop>sideLength-1 and loop<= 2*sideLength-1:
        print "*" + " "*(totalLength-2) + "*"

    if loop>=1 and loop<sideLength-1:
        print " "*(sideLength- 1- loop) + "*" +  " " * ((sideLength-2) + 2*(loop)) + "*" + " "*(sideLength- 1- loop)

    if loop>=2*sideLength-1 and loop<totalLength-1:
        print " "*(loop-totalLength+sideLength) + "*"+  " " *(totalLength-2*(loop-totalLength+sideLength+1)) + "*" + " "*(sideLength- 1- loop)

    loop+=1
```

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting and marking it as accepted (checkmark on the left of my answer).